# NullReferenceException when loading image from web

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

```
<Image Name="myImage" Width="160" Height="226"/>
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png, UriKind.Absolute));
myImage.Source = bi;
```

This is my code. Nothing difficult, nothing complicated. However, it gives me a NullReferenceException at "myImage.Source=bi". What's wrong?

Comment: What is `myImage` exactly? Are you sure it isn't `null`?

Comment: myImage is most likely not instantiated yet in this context.

Comment: I must admit that I suspect that either your code is erroneous or this is some sort of syntax that I'm not at all familiar with.

Comment: When are you setting the source of `myImage`? If it's in the page constructor, make sure it's after the call to `InitializeComponents`

Comment: Its not in the page constructor. Its in the loaded event of the page.

Comment: Is your Internet is running on emulator?

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png", UriKind.Absolute));

myImage.Source = bi;
```

this works. I tested. By the way " " is missing.

Comment: paste these lines after InitializeComponent(); and try again. The problem is  not these lines of code as @KooKiz mentioned.

Comment: Even if it works if I paste these lines in the page constructor, it doesn't solve my problem. What if I want to load the image when a user clicks a button?

Comment: @user1924391 This solution works perfect if you put it into Button Event. Maybe you have something wrong in your xaml.

Comment: worked for me.. same code .. loading image by clicking a button.. i think it would help if you paste the error too..